# String with breaks in form parameter copied to another attribute, without breaks, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given this line:

```
"correspondence"=>"asdfasdf\r\n\r\n\r\nasdfaasdfasdf\r\n\r\nasdf\r\n\r\nasdf\r\nasdf\r\nsadf"
```

which is the parameter of a field submission, and this line:

```
@musician_upgrade.correspondence_history += "\r\n\r\n#{Date.today}\r\n\r\nINPUTED BY: #{@fan.first_name}, id: #{@fan.id}\r\n\r\n" + params[:support_ticket][:correspondence]
```

why when i output @musician_upgrade.correspondence_history, it outputs as one line without breaks?

Comment: Do you output to console or to web page?

Comment: hey man :)   to a web page

Comment: ... if you have time for a passion project, you should consider joining our team, making this demo site.   then when it's time to make the real site, you'd have a guaranteed in on the pro team.

Comment: thanks, I'll think about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to translate `\n` to `<br\>` tag. You can use [simple_format](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/simple_format) helper for this

`<%= simple_format(@musician_upgrade.correspondence_history) %>`